# What is the relation between "sorting an array with only two distinct elements" and quicksort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm learning quicksort from Sedgwick's book. One of his exercise problems is

> Write a program that sorts an array that is known to contain just two distinct key values. 
> [View Solution](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/23quicksort/Sort2distinct.java.html)

I think I understand the solution. It runs in O(n). I don't however understand the relation between this and quicksort? I fail to see any sort of partitioning like in quick sort. All that is done here is deposit lesser and greater elements beyond respective boundaries pointed to by `lt` and `gt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is just like quicksort whit single pass.

Quick sort pseudo code:

```
1. Check stopping condition
2. Pick one number called pivot
3. Move smaller or equal elements than pivot on left part of array
4. Move greater elements than pivot on right part of array
5. Quicksort left part
6. Quicksort right part
```

Where soultion you looking for is same as quicsort exept 1,5,6

```
1. Pick one number called pivot
2. Move smaller or equal elements than pivot on left part of array
3. Move greater elements than pivot on right part of array
```

Comment: I was looking to explicitly place the pivot in between the left and right part of the array as I learnt from http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/23quicksort/Quick.java.html. In this case however,  I did not realise that the pivot(pointed to by 'lt') implicitly moves towards its position as a part of step 2 and step 3.